# How did Michael Faraday melt Sodium Chloride?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, melting-point

Michael Faraday melted sodium chloride in a silver spoon and ran an electric current through the molten salt, which released chlorine as a gas and left pure sodium behind.

Sodium chloride melts at $800\ \pu{^\circ C}$. How did Michael Faraday melt the salt?

*I know he invented the bunsen burner, but did he use that?

Comment: If you're incredulous that such temperatures were achievable those days, you may want to check out the average flame temperature of a [candle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candle)-- 800 degrees isn't a big deal. Or are you asking for the exact setup he used in his electrolysis apparatus?

Comment: I am asking for the exact setup. I found an open flame to be insufficient.

Comment: I came across an explanation of why NOT to use this method: http://yarchive.net/explosives/sodium_make.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is given in Faraday’s own work, *Experimental Researches in Electricity, Volume 1*, [freely available](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/14986/14986-h/14986-h.htm) thanks to The Project Gutenberg:

> 399. **Other substances, which could not be melted on glass, were fused by the lamp and blowpipe** on platina connected with one pole of the battery, and then a wire, connected with the other, dipped into them. In this way chloride of sodium, sulphate of soda, protoxide of lead, mixed carbonates of potash and soda, &c. &c., exhibited exactly the same phenomena as those already described: whilst liquid, they conducted and were decomposed; whilst solid, though very hot, they insulated the battery current even when four troughs were used.

The text above shows that the lamp in question is the **spirit lamp**, and the whole aparatus is [described here](http://physics.kenyon.edu/EarlyApparatus/Thermodynamics/Blow_Lamp/Blow_Lamp.html):

[image]

The crux of it is that an open flame might not have enough heat, so a conventional flame is simply contained into a more restricted space.